# Issues with notification bar like hello bar for fixed header menu bar website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am facing this same issue with almost all plugins like hello bar. I have a fixed menu bar already on top of website (www.germin8.com) .So with this bar to be functional i.e on open I want the entire website to push along with menu bar but that actually doesnt happen. Instead this bar overlaps my fixed menu bar and pushes the website contents down and not along with the menu bar.

Also the challenge is to make it responsive since the website runs on mobiles too.
Any sort of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post here some relevant code, preferably with a http://jsfiddle.net that demonstrates your exact problem. We are not going to start inspecting your live website and guess what your problem is.

Comment: i have a test website live at germtest.website.org

Comment: The scriplet used is just declaration of Hello bar at end of the body